# TcpListener.pending alternative java

Tags: java, sockets

**Hello..iknow that in c# you can check if a server has a pending connection by using the bool .pending(); but is there a way to do this in java? im asking cause i couldnt find anything related on the net...thanks
iwanna it to be like:**

```
ServerSocket srv=new ServerSocket(port);
if(srv.isPending())//How this can be done????
{
Socket Cl=srv.accept();
while(Cl.isConnected())
{
//read packet stream..........
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method available in java. You have to write a infinite loop to wait for a client connection like this.

```
ServerSocket srv=new ServerSocket(port);
while(true){
   /*Program will wait for a new client connection
     at this line and then proceeds further*/
   Socket client=srv.accept();
   // Rest of the code will continue here
}
```

Comment: there must be a way...cause doing this in an infinite loop is not resource effiecient correct me if im wrong.

Comment: In case of sockets I don't think so. Server is just listening to a client request.